# How to group list of duplicate continuous value in a list with a recursion function?

Tags: python, recursion, out-of-memory

I want to group consecutive values if it's duplicates and each value is just in one group, let's see my example below:

**Note**: `results` is an index of the value in `test_list`

```
test_list = ["1","2","1","2","1","1","5325235","2","62623","1","1"]
--->results = [[[0, 1], [2, 3]],
               [[4, 5], [9, 10]]]

test_list = ["1","2","1","1","2","1","5325235","2","62623","1","2","1","236","2388","626236437","1","2","1","236","2388"]
--->results = [[[9, 10, 11, 12, 13], [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]],
               [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]]
```

I build a recursive function:

```
def group_duplicate_continuous_value(list_label_group):

    # how to know which continuous value is duplicate, I implement take next number minus the previous number
    list_flag_grouping = [str(int(j.split("_")[0]) - int(i.split("_")[0])) +f"_{j}_{i}" for i,j in zip(list_label_group,list_label_group[1:])]

    # I find duplicate value in list_flag_grouping
    counter_elements = Counter(list_flag_grouping)
    list_have_duplicate = [k for k,v in counter_elements.items() if v > 1]

    if len(list_have_duplicate) > 0:
        list_final_index = group_duplicate_continuous_value(list_flag_grouping)
        # To return exactly value, I use index to define
        for k, v in list_final_index.items():
            temp_list = [v[i] + [v[i][-1] + 1] for i in range(0,len(v))]
            list_final_index[k] = temp_list
        check_first_cursive = list_label_group[0].split("_")
    
        # If we have many list grouping duplicate countinous value with different length, we need function below to return exactly results
        if len(check_first_cursive) > 1:
            list_temp_index = find_index_duplicate(list_label_group)
            list_duplicate_index = list_final_index.values()
            list_duplicate_index = [val for sublist in list_duplicate_index for val1 in sublist for val in val1]
            for k,v in list_temp_index.items():
                list_index_v = [val for sublist in v for val in sublist]
                if any(x in list_index_v for x in list_duplicate_index) is False:
                    list_final_index[k] = v
        
                    
        return list_final_index
    else:
        if len(list_label_group) > 0:
            check_first_cursive = list_label_group[0].split("_")
            if len(check_first_cursive) > 1:
                list_final_index = find_index_duplicate(list_label_group)
                return list_final_index
        list_final_index = None
        return list_final_index
```

Support function:

```
def find_index_duplicate(list_data):
    dups = defaultdict(list)
    for i, e in enumerate(list_data):
        dups[e].append([i])
    new_dict = {key:val for key, val in dups.items() if len(val) >1}
    return new_dict
```

But when I run with `test_list = [5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,1,2,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,1,2,5,5,5]`, it's very slow and make `out of memory` (~6GB). I knew a reason is stack overflow of my recursive function `group_duplicate_continuous_value` but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Hi. Could you please rephrase or explain in more detail? *"I have a list : `test_list = ["1","3","5","5","7","1","3","5"]`

The results should be: `index_results = [["0","1","2"],["5","6","7"]]` because `1,3,5` was existed >= 2 times."* I don't understand why the results are what they are. Where does this `[["0","1","2"],["5","6","7"]]` come from?

Comment: Your Q is unclear! index = 3 is 5 which is one of your duplicate items. why it is not in your result?

Comment: hi @Stef, `[["0","1","2"],["5","6","7"]]` is an index of `["1","3","5"]` (because `1,3,5` exist >= 2 times in `test_list`)

Comment: hi @nfn, index = 3 is 5 duplicate with index = 2 and index = 7 but index = 2 and index = 7 is other group.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dict of lists, where every item from the original list is a key in the dict, and every key is mapped to the list of its indices in the original list. For instance, your list `["1","3","5","5","7","1","3","5"]` would result in the dict `{"1": [0, 5], "3": [1, 6], "5": [2, 3, 7], "7": [4]}`.

Creating a dict of lists in this way is very idiomatic in python, and fast, too: it can be done by iterating just once on the list.

```py
def build_dict(l):
    d = {}
    for i, x in enumerate(l):
        d.setdefault(x, []).append(i)
    return d

l = ["1","3","5","5","7","1","3","5"]
d = build_dict(l)
print(d)
# {'1': [0, 5], '3': [1, 6], '5': [2, 3, 7], '7': [4]}
```

Then you can iterate on the dict to build two lists of indices:

```py
def build_index_results(l):
    d = build_dict(l)
    idx1, idx2 = [], []
    for v in d.values():
        if len(v) > 1:
            idx1.append(v[0])
            idx2.append(v[1])
    return idx1, idx2

print(build_index_results(l))
# ([0, 1, 2], [5, 6, 3])
```

Or using `zip`:

```py
from operator import itemgetter

def build_index_results(l):
    d = build_dict(l)
    return list(zip(*map(itemgetter(0,1), (v for v in d.values() if len(v) > 1))))

print(build_index_results(l))
# [(0, 1, 2), (5, 6, 3)]
```

I can't resist showcasing `more_itertools.map_reduce` for this:

```py
from more_itertools import map_reduce
from operator import itemgetter

def build_index_results(l):
    d = map_reduce(enumerate(l),
                   keyfunc=itemgetter(1),
                   valuefunc=itemgetter(0),
                   reducefunc=lambda v: v[:2] if len(v) > 1 else None
    )
    return list(zip(*filter(None, d.values())))

print(build_index_results(l))
# [(0, 1, 2), (5, 6, 3)]
```

Comment: thanks for your solution, but `l` will have many group duplicates.
example with : `l = ["1","2","1","2","1","1","5325235","2","62623","1","1"]`. The results should be : `[[0,1],[2,3]]` and `[[4,5],[9,10]]`.
Your solution is just returns **one** group.

Comment: @ToanNguyenPhuoc I think you don't realise how hard it is to understand what you want from the examples you have given. Please explain your problem in more detail in your question post. I'm not going to keep guessing what you want from one example, only to be corrected with a new example that behaves differently.

Comment: I'm so sorry for that, I updated my post.